# Console.Clear only clearing certain selections?

Tags: c#, debugging

i have a menu.Basically, i need to fix this error. I had it working fine, until now. With the `Console.Clear` on, I can ONLY use 1 or 8. 2-7 just clears out.It SHOULD display "You need to create a student first".  If I turn `Console.Clear` off, then it works. However, I need it on since that is the part that resets the menu. Plus it also runs the line that is only supposed to run when you exit. I didn't change anything major.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student currentStudent = null;

        bool running = true; // Logic 1
        string input = "";

        while(running)
        {
            // display menu
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Main menu: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create a student");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Add a course to the current student");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Remove a course from the current student");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Add grades for a course");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Display student info");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Display grades for a course");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Display all grades");
            Console.WriteLine("8. Exit");
            Console.Write("Enter a selection: (1 - 8): ");
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            Console.WriteLine();
            // handle choices
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            switch(input)
            {
                case "1":
                case "create a student":
                    {
                        Console.Write("What is the students first name? ");
                        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("What is the students last name? ");
                        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                        currentStudent = new Student(firstName, lastName);

                        Console.Write("How old is the student? ");
                        string studentAge = Console.ReadLine(); // Logic 2
                        int age;

                        while(!int.TryParse(studentAge, out age))
                        {
                            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
                            studentAge = Console.ReadLine();

                        }

                        currentStudent.Age = age;

                        Console.Write("What is the students address? ");
                        currentStudent.Address = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("What is the students email? ");
                        currentStudent.Email = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("What is the students phone number? ");
                        currentStudent.Phone = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":                      
                case "add a course to the current student":
                    {
                        if(currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.AddACourse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                case "remove a course from the current student":
                    {
                        if (currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.RemoveACourse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "4":
                case "add grades for a course":
                    {
                        if (currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.AddGradesForACourse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "5":
                case "display student info":
                    {
                        if (currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.DisplayInfo();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "6":
                case "display grades for a course":
                    {
                        if (currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.DisplayGradesForACourse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "7":
                case "display all grades":
                    {
                        if (currentStudent != null)
                        {
                            currentStudent.DisplayAllGrades();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "8":
                case "exit":
                    {
                        running = false; // Logic 6
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }


            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to exit");
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Student Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Student
    {
        static int _nextStudentIDNum = 1000;

    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    string _email;
    string _address;
    string _phoneNumber;
    int _age;
    int _studentIdNum;
    List<Course> _courses;

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _studentIdNum = ++_nextStudentIDNum;
        _courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{_lastName}, {_firstName}";

        }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
        }
    }
    public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _age;
        }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
        }
    }
    public int StudentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _studentIdNum;
        }
        set
        {
            _studentIdNum = value;
        }
    }
    public List<Course> Courses
    {
        get
        {
            return _courses;
        }
    }

    private int SelectCourse(string message)
    {
        int len = _courses.Count;
        int index = -1;

        if (len > 0) //Logic 3
        {
            for (index = 0; index < len; ++index)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{index + 1}. {_courses[index].Title}");
            }
            Console.Write(message);
            string selection = Console.ReadLine();

            while (!int.TryParse(selection, out index) || (index < 1 || index > len))
            {
                Console.Write("Please make a valid selection: ");
                selection = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            --index;
        }

        return index;
    }

    public void AddACourse()
    {
        string input;

        Console.Write("How many assignments are in the course? ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        int numAssignments = 0;

        while (!int.TryParse(input, out numAssignments))
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Course course = new Course(numAssignments);

        Console.Write("What is the courses title? ");
        course.Title = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("What is the courses description? ");
        course.Description = Console.ReadLine();

        _courses.Add(course);
    }

    public void RemoveACourse()
    {
        int index = SelectCourse("Select a course to remove. (Enter the number): ");

        if (index == -1) //Logic 8
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No courses to remove.  Try adding one first.");
        }
        else
        {
            _courses.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }

    public void AddGradesForACourse()
    {
        int index = SelectCourse("Select a course to add grades for. (Enter the number): ");

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No course to add grades to.  Try adding one first.");
        }
        else
        {
            _courses[index].AddGrades();
        }
    }

    public void DisplayGradesForACourse()
    {
        int index = SelectCourse("Select a course to display grades for. (Enter the number): ");

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No course to display grades for.  Try adding one first.");
        }
        else
        {
            _courses[index].DisplayGrades();
        }
    }

    public void DisplayAllGrades()
    {
        foreach (Course c in _courses)
        {
            c.DisplayGrades(); //Logic 7
        }
    }

    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {Name}\nAge: {Age}\nAddress: {Address}\nPhone: {Phone}\nEmail: {Email}");
    }
}
}
```

Course Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Course
    {
        string _title;
        string _description;
        Grade[] _grades;
        int _graded;

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
        }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }
    public Grade[] Grades
    {
        get
        {
            return _grades;
        }
    }

    public Course(int numberOfAssignments)
    {
        _grades = new Grade[numberOfAssignments];
        _graded = 32;
    }

    public void AddGrades()
    {
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _grades.Length; ++i)
            {
                _grades[i] = new Grade();

                Console.Write($"Enter a description for assignment {i + 1}: ");
                _grades[i].Description = Console.ReadLine();


                string input;
                float value;

                Console.Write($"Enter the grade earned for assignment {i + 1} as a percentage (0 - 100): ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                while (!float.TryParse(input, out value)) // Logic 4
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                _grades[i].PercentEarned = value;

                Console.Write($"Enter assignment {i + 1}'s weight of total grade as a percentage (0 - 100): ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                while (!float.TryParse(input, out value))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                _grades[i].Weight = value;
            }
        }
        while (ValidateWeightTotal() == false); 

            _graded = 0;


    }

    private bool ValidateWeightTotal()
    {
        float precisionFactor = 0.001f;
        float _totalWeight = 0;
        bool result = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _grades.Length; ++i)
        {
            _totalWeight += _grades[i].Weight;
        }

        if(_totalWeight < 100 + precisionFactor && _totalWeight > 100 - precisionFactor)
        {
            result = true;
        }

        if (result == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Weight total = {_totalWeight} instead of 100.\nPlease enter the values again.\n");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public float GetFinalGrade()
    {
        bool weightsAreValid = ValidateWeightTotal();
        float finalGrade = 0;

        if(weightsAreValid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _grades.Length; ++i)
            {
                finalGrade += _grades[i].GetPercentOfFinalGrade();
            }
        }

        return finalGrade;
    }

    public void DisplayGrades()
    {
        if (_graded == 0)
        {
            float total = 0f;
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Title: {Title}");
            for (int i = 0; i < _grades.Length; ++i)
            {
                Grade grade = _grades[i];
                total += grade.GetPercentOfFinalGrade();
                Console.WriteLine($"Desc: {grade.Description}\nEarned: {grade.PercentEarned}\nPercent towards final grade: {grade.GetPercentOfFinalGrade()}\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Grade for the course: {total}");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please add grades first.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Grade Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    class Grade
    {
        string _description;
        float _percentEarned;
        float _weight;

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }
    public float PercentEarned
    {
        get
        {
            return _percentEarned;
        }
        set
        {
            _percentEarned = value;

            if (value < 0.0f || value > 100.0f)
            {
                //_percentEarned = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Percent earned was less than 0 or greater than 100 so value was set to 0.");
            }
            else
            {
                _percentEarned = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public float Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return _weight;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0.0f || value > 100.0f)
            {
                //_weight = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Weight was less than 0 or greater than 100 so value was set to 0.");
            }
            else
            {
                _weight = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public float GetPercentOfFinalGrade()
    {
        float result = (_percentEarned * _weight) / 100;
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add your Student class please

Comment: Here you go. Added

Comment: add Course class as well please i need to run it to solve your problem :)

Comment: Phew, ok I added the other classes

Comment: what is the type of project you created ? i have just created a console based project and its running fine, no menu gets clear off

Comment: https://onetimesecret.com/secret/c8t4qai6b3kmsq8vb1ggmwzxsusv035
go to think link copy the code and run it if it is fixed let me know ,i will write it up as answer and then you can accept the answer

Comment: What!? Yeah its a console. Even if you select 2-7, it doesnt instantly clear it? The menu is always on yes, but the output that is supposed to show up doesnt show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is to clear the console at the End of the Loop and make it Stay there for a While just to show user the output you would do something like this 
i have Added like , 3000 means for 3000 milliseconds that are 3 seconds we will show the user error and then we will clear the output and show the menu again,use 3 seconds or 5 seconds(5000),what ever you want, and then clear the output

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.Clear();


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student currentStudent = null;

            bool running = true; // Logic 1
            string input = "";

            while (running)
            {
                // display menu

                Console.WriteLine("Main menu: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Create a student");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Add a course to the current student");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Remove a course from the current student");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Add grades for a course");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Display student info");
                Console.WriteLine("6. Display grades for a course");
                Console.WriteLine("7. Display all grades");
                Console.WriteLine("8. Exit");
                Console.Write("Enter a selection: (1 - 8): ");
                input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                Console.WriteLine();
                // handle choices
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                switch (input)
                {
                    case "1":
                    case "create a student":
                        {
                            Console.Write("What is the students first name? ");
                            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

                            Console.Write("What is the students last name? ");
                            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                            currentStudent = new Student(firstName, lastName);

                            Console.Write("How old is the student? ");
                            string studentAge = Console.ReadLine(); // Logic 2
                            int age;

                            while (!int.TryParse(studentAge, out age))
                            {
                                Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
                                studentAge = Console.ReadLine();

                            }

                            currentStudent.Age = age;

                            Console.Write("What is the students address? ");
                            currentStudent.Address = Console.ReadLine();

                            Console.Write("What is the students email? ");
                            currentStudent.Email = Console.ReadLine();

                            Console.Write("What is the students phone number? ");
                            currentStudent.Phone = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2":
                    case "add a course to the current student":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.AddACourse();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                    case "remove a course from the current student":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.RemoveACourse();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "4":
                    case "add grades for a course":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.AddGradesForACourse();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "5":
                    case "display student info":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.DisplayInfo();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "6":
                    case "display grades for a course":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.DisplayGradesForACourse();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "7":
                    case "display all grades":
                        {
                            if (currentStudent != null)
                            {
                                currentStudent.DisplayAllGrades();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please create a student first.");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "8":
                    case "exit":
                        {
                            running = false; // Logic 6
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }


                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to exit");
                //Console.ReadKey();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well its giving me errors trying to use it. But i mean I am really frustrated because I have no idea why it clears ONLY 2-7 but it works fine when the Clear is off (besides it not resetting the menu)

Comment: Ok nevermind it works. It is still showing the exit code "You have chosen to exit"

Comment: you can add the code i have wrote to you in every case in switch just move it to every switch case and you are done 
+ pelase mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Ok I just moved it. Fixed it. Thank you. This at least makes it work.